# Chrome NPAPI method for making it downloading url

Tags: plugins, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, npapi, firebreath

I've recently got into using FireBreath for some simple task: download a clicked url. Is there a built-in method or something else with which i can add the url to Chrome's native download queue? or at least load up a Save Link As.. dialog (that would be ok too)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can show a save dialog by using the native OS calls to do so; for example, on the Mac you'd use NSSavePanel. That won't hand the download off to the browser though, it would just give you a user-selected filename to download to. You'd still have to do the download yourself.

NPAPI doesn't have a way to tell the browser to start a download using its UI. That would be something that would be an extension API if it existed (and what you'd want to file a request for if it didn't), not part of NPAPI.

Comment: i see, thanks a lot. Now i see what you mean when you described a method for Mac

Comment: if someone else is seeking the answer, i figured it out like this: first, download the file using XHR (javascript), then pass the downloaded string to NPAPI for it to save to a file (that's a c++ part), so that means i had to make NPAPI only for autosaving in a file

Answer (score 0):

Send the following HTTP header along with the content.

```
Content-Disposition: attachment
```

Optionally with `; filename="`*`filename here`*`"`.

Comment: i don't have access to the server

Answer (score 0):

If you want to download a clicked URL with FireBreath then you're not going to get a download dialog; if you need a download dialog, why are you using FireBreath?

The easiest way to get a download dialog is to set window.location to the URL you want to download and wait for the browser to pop the dialog up itself; you can do this with FireBreath or with javascript, it works the same way.

Comment: this won't work in Chrome for mp3s and other extensions for which the plugins are defined (they intercept and playback for example).. and how does Flash display a dialog when it downloads a file with FileReference.download() method then?

Comment: Presumably flash creates its own dialog using native OS calls, as smorgan suggests.